# parent() grabbing siblings as well

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

In the example on the following page, I would like the "active" class to apply to the parent of the active link:

http://socalragdolls.com/jquerytest.html

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li class="top" id="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="kittens">Kittens</a>
            <ul id="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="caring">Caring for a Ragdoll</a></li>
                <li><a href="kittens">Current Litter</a></li>
                <li><a href="jquerytest.html">Future Litters</a></li>
                <li><a href="parents">Parents</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="reserving">Reserving a Kitten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about">Cattery</a></li>
                <li><a href="proprietor">Proprietor</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Essentially, when a visitor is on the page (jquerytest.html), I want the parent li "Kittens" to be active as well.

Here's the current jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#topnav a").each(function() {
        if(this.href == window.location || this.href == document.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname)
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li.active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, this highlights all siblings of the child .active li along with the parent, which I definitely don't want.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd check that the if statement in your each block is returning what you'd expect. Also, I don't trust if statements without {}; especially in JS. I'd try adding the braces.

Answer (score 1):

It does not select everything..

It selects just the parent. The problem is with your CSS rule for .active which styles the whole `li` (*and since the `ul` is a child of the `li` it **looks like** all siblings are selected*).

Just create a css rule for `.active ul{background-color:white;}`

---

If the issue lies with the red border and not the background-color then the culprit is this part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li ul li.active').siblings().css('border', '1px solid red');
    $('li ul li.active').siblings().css('background-color', '#333');
});
```

but that is too obvious to be the real problem..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are applying the style to the whole `ul`, that's why it "changes" all its children as well... You might need to reset the `background-color` on `ul` using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second script should be like this:

**EDIT**

```
$('li.active').closest("li").find("a").addClass('active');
```

So with this we only add the `active` class to the anchor. What was happening is that you're adding the class to the whole li, which include children.

Hope this helps
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually highlighting the siblings, it is highlighting the parent `li` and all the content inside it.

I would put the active class on the kitten link instead, or you might add a different class name, like `active-trail` to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul says, the whole `li` of the parent has the background, which encapsulates the child `ul`. One way to avoid this would be to use a background image, which is only as tall as the parent link, and does not repeat on the y axis.